# How to wrap function and pause

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have this on click function, that I need to add another function inside of to do a  pause and finish, and then resume the onclick function to continue.
-function to call and pause : errorCheckingOrder(). see below

Here is function onclick:

```
        $('#payment_submit_order').on('click', function(){

                    errorCheckingOrder();//here is the function calling it

        var data = {fName : $("#returnfirstName").val(), lName: $("#returnlastName").val(), add1: $("#returnaddress1").val(), add2: $("#returnaddress2").val()};
        data.city = $("#returncity").val();
        data.state = $("#returnstate").val();
        data.mail = $("#returnemail").val();
        data.zipcode = $("#returnzipcode").val();
        var returnAddress = saveAddress(data);

        var value = $('input[name=shippingType]:checked').val();
        if(value == 0){
            var address = saveAddress();
            var shipping = ($('input[name=shippingmethod]:checked').val()*productCart.length).toFixed(2);
            for(var i in productCart) {
                productCart[i].addressId = address;
                productCart[i].shippingmethod = shipping;
                productCart[i].returnAddress = returnAddress;
            }
        }else{
            for(var i in productCart) {
                var address = $("#selectProductAddress_"+productCart[i].uProductID).val();
                productCart[i].addressId = address;
                productCart[i].returnAddress = returnAddress;
                var shipping = 0;
                $('input[name^="shippingmethod_"]').each(function(){
                    if($(this).is(":checked")){
                        shipping += parseFloat($(this).val());
                    }
                });
                shipping = shipping.toFixed(2);
                productCart[i].shippingmethod = shipping;
            }
        }
               });
```

And here is the function for doing the error checking/validations. Which we need to go thru first, then once good. Continue. the function above.

```
        //Personlize & Customize Validation placed here
        $(function errorCheckingOrder(){
            bindValidation("shipping_gift_card","${pageContext.response.locale}");
            $("#payment_submit_order").click(function(){
                return isValidation("shipping_gift_card","${pageContext.response.locale}");
            });
        });
```

Please help how we get, the validations to go thru first, then run the payment_order on click function????

Comment: It's good to make large code samples self-contained and save to [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net). Makes it easier on people playing around with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's better to catch the submit event on the form.
This way if an user presses the enter key on a form field you can still catch the submit event and reject it with event.preventDefault() if validation fails

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

```
$( "#form_id" ).submit(function( event ) {
    if(yourValidationFunction() === false){
      event.preventDefault();
    }
//else the submit will pe performed
});
```

The button can still be made to work with

```
$('#payment_submit_order').click(function() {
  $( "#form_id" ).submit();
});
```

Comment: Why we did not see this, we tried your code and it seems to be doewn the path we are hoping will work..

      $( "#form_id" ).submit(function( event ) {
        if(yourValidationFunction() === false){
      event.preventDefault();
        }
     //else the submit will pe performed
    });

Thank you, we will update as we test away.

Comment: We would like to have the on submit, fire off the validations, once validation are good (or return false), then resume the submit, function.

Can you take look at our Thread and give us some direct guidance.

Truly appreciate this..............

you replied, but we do not understand...